# Simple C++ calculator always outputs 16

Tags: c++, codeblocks, calculator

I'm new to programming so please write your answer as basic as possible. I made a simple calulator in C++. It's supposed to add 2 numbers but for some reason the output is always 16, no matter the numbers. Can someone explain this to me? This is the code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int sum = a + b;

    cout << "Enter a number: ";
    cin >> a;

    cout << "Enter a second number: ";
    cin >> b;

    cout << sum;

    return 0;
}
```

But, when i do this (creating the `int sum` first and then assigning it later), it works:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int sum;

    cout << "Enter a number: ";
    cin >> a;

    cout << "Enter a second number: ";
    cin >> b;

    sum = a + b;

    cout << sum;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Order matters, as you've noticed. Statements are executed from top to bottom. So when you do `int sum = a + b` the values of `a` and `b` are *indeterminate* (and using them will lead to *undefined behavior*)

Comment: `int a; int b;int sum = a + b;` -- C++ programs work top-down.  It doesn't store `a + b` as a formula that is looked up later on.

Comment: `int sum = a + b;` when `a` and `b` do not have values yet, is undefined behaviour. Not sure what you'd expect to happen.

Answer (score 3):

```
int sum = a + b;
```

Is not an algebraic rule, it is a statement evaluated at that point in the sequence of statements.

Just do it after your inputs.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example, you're initializing the `sum` variable before the initialization of `a` and `b` so before initialization, the `a` and `b` will contain some garbage value and that's why you're getting output 16 the garbage value can be anything. Just initialize your sum variable after `a` and `b` variables have some user inputted values.

And if you're doing some addition then it's a good practice to initialize your result variable(`sum`) with zero `sum=0` so it also doesn't contain any garbage values

Answer (score 1):

When you use

```
int sum = a + b;
```

`sum` initilized to whatever `a + b` evaluates to. The value of `sum` does not change when you set the values of `a` and `b` after that statement. In your case, neither `a` nor `b` has been initialized before that statement. Hence, it causes undefined behavior.

The second version of your program works correctly since you are assigning `a + b` to `sum` after `a` and `b` have been assigned values from user input.